# NSNotificationCenter selector not being called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsnotification, nsnotificationcenter

In my iPad app, in one class I register for a notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectedList:) name:@"TTSelectedList" object:nil];
```

My `selectedList:` method looks like this:

```
- (void)selectedList:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"received notification");
}
```

Then in another class (a `UITableViewController`) I post that notification when a row is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"posting notification");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TTSelectedList" object:nil];
}
```

I can confirm that the notification is being posted, because "posting notification" is logged to the console, but "received notification" is never called, meaning that the notification isn't received and the selector hasn't been called. I can't figure out what's causing this.

Thanks

Comment: Something stupid, but which left me puzzled for a while. I had the same issue. In my case, I didn't notice a subclass had method with the same selector as the one I was trying to declare in the parent class.

Comment: Had this myself, also something stupid: I was posting a notification with a lowercase letter instead of a capital letter. They're case sensitive!

Comment: In my case I created an object in local method, So the observer class dealloc during notification fire from another class. You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328439/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-not-working-in-release-mode-but-works-in-debug

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you're not actually calling `addObserver:selector:name:object:`. You don't have a logging line there; are you sure that code is running?

The second most likely cause is that you're calling `removeObserver:` before the notification is posted. This is most commonly in `dealloc` (which should *always* call `removeObserver` if you've ever observed anything). The error here would be that your observing object has deallocated before the notification.

Comment: You were right, I was creating the object that was the observer in Interface Builder, and it wasn't being retained by anything. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem. I added the observer in the `init` method instead of `initWithStyle`

Comment: If you use IB to make your stuff, chances are that init will not get called. Use initWithCoder or awakeWithNib depending on what you want to do.

Comment: In my case issue with the local instance of listener class. Please check and vote if helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328439/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-not-working-in-release-mode-but-works-in-debug