# NSNotificationCenter selector method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

Hi i am trying to use  NSNotification center  in my application.The selector method is not being called from the code.I found similar questions in this site like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198996/nsnotificationcenter-selector-not-being-called), but still i am unable to resolve the error.

i am posting notification in appdelegate did finish launching as:
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ualert" object:self   userInfo:userDict];`

adding an observer in one of the view controller as:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(remoteNotificationReceived:)
                                             name:@"ualert"
                                           object:nil];
```

my selector method is:

```
- (void)remoteNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
      NSLog(@"Notification: %@", notification.userInfo);

  }
```

removing observer as:

```
    - (void)dealloc
   {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure yo are posting your notification AFTER having registered to it ?

Can you paste your did finish launching method ?

Comment: You are posting notification before registering to the notification center

Comment: Thanks @jfgrang. I understood the concept now. I should register to the notification first and then post it.But i am working on Apple push notifications. I receive user notification data in Appdelegate. I would like to share the notification data to all parts of application. So how to apply this NSNotificationcenter concept in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting `ualert` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` which will necessarily occur before your view controller is loaded (and therefore before you have added the observer for the notification).

Comment: Thanks @keller.I am working on Apple push notifications. I receive user notification data in Appdelegate. I would like to share the notification data to all parts of application. So how can i apply this NSNotificationcenter concept in this scenario?

Comment: If your app is running in the foreground, you can use `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and post an `NSNotification` in the manner you described in your question. However, if you need special handling upon launch (beyond simply opening your app or performing an operation that can be done entirely in your AppDelegate such as showing a UIAlertView), it is a little trickier. One technique would be to hold a reference to applicable objects from the push payload in your AppDelegate and check for the existence of those objects once your view controller loads.

Comment: Yes @keller. I am able to access the push payload objects in one of my view controller.But i would like to know the best programmatic approach for that like protocol delegation,Notification center,Shared instances..etc.